# What Linux-Hosted Web Language/Framework is most like asp.net mvc 5+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, linux

I know this is the kind of question that usually gets deleted, but I have to find some answers. I want to build a project in a new technology more suitable to hosting on a Linux server, but I like the way things are done in ASP.NET MVC. I've looked at Rails a bit but I've heard that Rails performs and scales poorly. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails doesn't scale well, but depending on your needs you may never have to worry about it.

My guess is you'd be most comfortable with something like CakePHP or just PHP and whatever MVC framework. It's pretty C# like, and it's FAST!

Python/Django is also a good choice. (My personal favorite)

Comment: I don't think you can even compare PHP speed with C# speed, if we talk about scaling issues, definitely don't go with PHP, I highly suggest Java with Play framework possibly. Also, CakePHP is one of the *slowest* PHP frameworks available (while I like it), it's definitely not a good choice

Comment: Good point, I should clarify, faster than Ruby on Rails and Python.

Comment: Fire-Dragon-DoL are you saying PHP is much faster than C# or much slower? Sorry, but I really know very little about anything but Microsoft's tech.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm saying PHP is much slower than C#. C# is roughly as fast as Java, which are just behind C++ in the speed chart. PHP is not statically typed and doesn't need a compile step, overall these are stuff that counts if you need brutal speed.